# Bold Sans Font Identification

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Does anyone recognize this font? I have found quite a few that are similar but no exact matches. I've run through every automatic font-ID site listed [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info) and the closest I've found is Twentieth Century Bold Condensed but it's not quite correct.

[image: efgilnrtu]

These letters are from a company logo, they were originally slightly skewed and this is unfortunately the highest resolution version they have available.

Comment: If it's a company logo, keep in mind that it might be custom made lettering instead of a full typeface.

Comment: The person that made the logo is still at the company, he claims to have just used a regular font and 'smooshed it around a bit' but he does not have the original files anymore. Great point though.

Comment: I'm all for smooshing around fonts! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a custom, it's a catalog font:

[Infinite Justice](https://www.dafont.com/es/infinite-justice.font?text=efgilnrtu&psize=l) via dafont.com

[image]

Comment: This is the exact font used, even has the same cutouts in the uppercase letters!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might be a skewed/smooshed Univers Black (with a custom t).

[image: Univers Black]

Comment: I don't know if this is quite right. The "g", "n", "r", and especially "t" look different. It'd take a fair big of editing to get the one in question

Comment: When suggesting a font please make sure to site a location it can be found and more detail about it as the name could be used for different fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that the t is specially-created, and the cross-bar of f is too deep too. Those features should be discounted.

The flat top to e and g and the reduced serifs on n and u would indicate that either the letters have been stretched horizontally, or they are "double-strike" like the artificial "faux-bold" applications sometimes use to create a non-existent true boldface.

If the letters were simply stretched, then squeezing them horizontally should produce recognisable results:

[image: Condensed version]

That doesn't actually appear to help much, although the f now shows a fairly large radius for the hook at the top. Neither Univers nor Helvetica have that sort of radius for f; it's a sharper bend. It does indicate that it's a faux bold.

However, there aren't many fonts where the ends of e and g are horizontal (not Arial then) or the flags of f and r are horizontal with vertical ends. Lower-case e appears to be broadly symmetrical. The counters of g, n and u don't have corners.

Here's a double-strike version of Bitstream's Swiss 721 Medium (a Helvetica lookalike):

[image: Bitsteam Swiss 721 Md double-strike]
[image: Double-strike solidified]

That is looking more like the example, although the hook on the f is still too sharply curved.

I think it will be a question of finding an f which is not sharply curved and then playing with the rest of the forms and offsetting a double-strike. I don't have such an f available to identify it.

Univers Black as suggested by Don Citarella is a better-looking, more readily-available and more easily-reproduced alternative which would certainly bear consideration for adoption.